# Find the marginal density $f_Y(y)$ of a random vector $(X,Y)$.

Tags: probability-distributions

Given a (continuous) bivariate random vector $(X,Y)$ with a probability density:

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{l}\tfrac{1}{y}e^{-(y+\tfrac{x}{y})} & \text{if }x>0 \text{ and } y>0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{array} \right.$$

Find the marginal density $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ and show whether $X$ and $Y$ are stochastically independent.

In my attempt, I tried to calculate the marginal densities as follows:

$$\begin{align*}f_Y(y) 
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{XY}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\tfrac{1}{y}e^{-(y+\tfrac{x}{y})}\mathrm{d}x\\
&= -\lim_{N \to \infty} \left[ e^{-(y+\tfrac{x}{y})} \right]_0^N \\
&= -\lim_{N \to \infty} (e^{-(y+\tfrac{N}{y})}-e^{-(y+\tfrac{0}{y})})\\
&= e^{-y}-0 = \frac{1}{e^y}
\end{align*}$$
$\\$
$$\begin{align*}f_X(x) 
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{XY}(x,y)\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\tfrac{1}{y}e^{-(y+\tfrac{x}{y})}\mathrm{d}y\\
\end{align*}$$

But I get stuck at solving this last integrals. How should this be solved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The expression for $f_X(x)$ is not elementary. In fact, the integral is a [defining integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E10) for the [Macdonald function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_%3a_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1):
$$
   f_X(x) = \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-y - \frac{x}{y}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} =  \left.\left( \underbrace{\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^\nu \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-t-\frac{z^2}{4t} \right) \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t^{\nu+1}}}_{2 K_\nu\left(z\right)}\right)\right|_{\nu=0,z=2 \sqrt{x}} = 2 K_0\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)
$$
where $x$ was assumed positive. Anyhow, you readily conclude that $f_{X,Y}(x,y) \not= f_X(x) f_Y(y)$.